# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getEntityManager" of class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning symfony and I would like to have a search bar to show user with email. But I got and error

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getEntityManager" of class "App\Repository\SearchRepository".
```

If someone can help me or explain me how to do it's would be very nice. Thanks

In SearchRepository

```
class SearchRepository
{

    public function findAllWithSearch($email){
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
            'SELECT u
            FROM App\Entity\User u
            WHERE u.email :email'
        )->setParameter('email', $email);
        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

In SearchController

```
class SearchController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/search/", name="admin_search")
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function searchUser(SearchRepository $repository, Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->query->get('search');
        $comments = $repository->findllWithSearch($q);
        return $this->render('admin/search/search.html.twig',
        [            'user' => $repository,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and search.twig.html

```
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="search" name="search" value="" placeholder="Recherche.." />
        <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Is that the exact definition of your `SearchRepository`? Where did you define the method `getEntityManager()` in that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doctrine documentation:

> A repository object provides many ways to retrieve entities of the
>   specified type. By default, the repository instance is of type
>   `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`. You can also use custom repository
>   classes.

So, if your search is going to deal with `User` objects, you can use the standard `UserRepository` by doing the following in your `Controller`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/search/", name="admin_search")
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
public function searchUser(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->query->get('search');
    // Get standard repository
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findBy(['email' => $q]); // Or use the magic method ->findByEmail($q);

    // Present your results
    return $this->render('admin/search/search_results.html.twig', 
        ['user' => $user]);
}
```

There is no need for a custom repository for your use case, but if you want to create one and use it for autowiring you must extend `ServiceEntityRepository`, a container-friendly base repository class provided by Symfony. You can get more details in [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository). In this case you might want to also review [how to annotate your entity](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) to tell the `EntityManager` that you'll be using a custom repository.

Sidenote: By default, the `action` attribute of the `form` defaults to the same route you are visiting, so if that fragment is part of a layout you'll have to set it explicitly to your `SearchController` action: `action="{{ path('admin_search') }}"`

Answer (score 3):

**Quick Answer**

SearchRepository needs to extend \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
class SearchRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
public function findAllWithSearch($email)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
        'SELECT u
        FROM App\Entity\User u
        WHERE u.email :email'
    )->setParameter('email', $email);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

**Fix your Application's Architecture**

Looks like you're at the very beginning of your journey. The above code will fix your issue, but you need to pay attention to the architecture of your code.

- Repository Classes are like containers for your entities.
- You would not have a repository for Search (unless you're storing Search entities).
- You would usually put this into a UserRepository. Which should be charged with the responsibility of being a repo for User Entity objects.
- There are magic methods within Repositories that will allow you to find Entities.

Using your specific example, you could use something like

```
$repoInstance->findByEmail($email);
```

within your controller and this will return all records entities that
   match your email address.

**More about Working with Doctrine Repositories**

For more information on how repositories work, consume and experiment with the documentation from this link:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

If `UserRepository` already exists and extend `ServiceEntityRepository` try to move `findAllWithSearch` to `UserRepository`.

If not your SearchRepository must looks like this

```
 /**
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */

class UserSearchRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function findByEmail(string $email)
    {
        return $this->findBy(['email' => $email]);
    }
}
```